# Oracle query execution error

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

I have successfully executed the following query in TOAD, but not executing through my java code.

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(amtacctdr)-sum(amtacctcr),0) FROM fact_acct WHERE  to_char(dateacct,'MM') ='01' AND to_char(dateacct,'YYYY')='2013' AND Account_ID=513 AND AD_Client_ID=11 AND AD_Org_ID=50001  AND postingtype='A';
```

The following is the error code obtained.

> ===========> DB.getSQLValue:  SELECT COALESCE(sum(amtacctdr)-sum(amtacctcr),0) FROM fact_acct WHERE 
>   to_char(dateacct,'MM') ='01' AND to_char(dateacct,'YYYY')='2013' AND
>   Account_ID=513 AND AD_Client_ID=11 AND AD_Org_ID=50001  AND
>   postingtype='A'; [12] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911:
>   invalid character ; State=22019; ErrorCode=911

What is the syntax error in the statement?

**Updation**

```
try
        {
            pstmt = prepareStatement(sql, trxName);
            setParameters(pstmt, params);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next())
                retValue = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
            else
                log.fine("No Value " + sql);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            //log.log(Level.SEVERE, sql, getSQLException(e));
            throw new DBException(e, sql);
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs, pstmt);
            rs = null; pstmt = null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your java code actually running the query? I am lead to believe you aren't escaping a special character properly.

Comment: Its a simple java code. I have updated the same. The 'sql' variable String contain the same SQL statement that I mentioned.

Comment: semicolon at the end of the sql may cause the problem

Comment: @Multisync is more than likely correct but you didn't include the variable declaration in your code.

Comment: @mmmmmpie - you can see it in the error message though, including the trailing semicolon.

Comment: @Multisync You are correct. Semi column was the culprit :)